# Difference between using "ON .. AND" and "WHERE" in LEFT JOIN

Tags: mysql, database-performance

Are these two queries effectively same or any difference between them *from execution perspective*? If they are same would there be any performance difference between these two?

1.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A tbl_a 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B tbl_b ON (tbl_a.srno_a = tbl_b.srno_b) 
AND tbl_a.srno_a = 1997
```

and

2.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_A tbl_a 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_B tbl_b ON (tbl_a.srno_a = tbl_b.srno_b) 
WHERE tbl_a.srno_a = 1997
```

Comment: @Norbert van Nobelen - it complete different result. i will add an answer

Comment: @BerndBuffen : SOrry, read inner instead of left join. Yes, different answer.

Comment: You can answer this for yourself as easily as ask us. The result sets will be different, and the parsed query is also different. You can use `EXPLAIN EXTENDED...` followed by `SHOW WARNINGS` to see what that looks like

Comment: Use `ON` to say how the tables are related.  Use `WHERE` to filter the results.  Let the optimizer figure out how to do the job.

Comment: @RickJames: That helped to reduce lot of confusion. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you can see the difference:

if you use WHERE the result will be smaller. look at the sample.

**sample**

**my tables**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> select * from table1;
+--------+------------+
| id     | val        |
+--------+------------+
| 000001 | tabe 1 --1 |
| 000002 | tabe 1 --2 |
| 000003 | tabe 1 --3 |
| 000004 | tabe 1 --4 |
| 000005 | tabe 1 --5 |
| 000006 | tabe 1 --6 |
+--------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]> select * from table2;
+--------+------------+
| id     | val        |
+--------+------------+
| 000001 | tabe 2 --1 |
| 000002 | tabe 2 --2 |
| 000004 | tabe 2 --4 |
| 000005 | tabe 2 --5 |
| 000006 | tabe 2 --6 |
+--------+------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]>
```

**JOIN with AND**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> SELECT *
    -> FROM table1 t1
    -> LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2. id AND t2.val ='tabe 2 --4';
+--------+------------+--------+------------+
| id     | val        | id     | val        |
+--------+------------+--------+------------+
| 000004 | tabe 1 --4 | 000004 | tabe 2 --4 |
| 000001 | tabe 1 --1 |   NULL | NULL       |
| 000002 | tabe 1 --2 |   NULL | NULL       |
| 000003 | tabe 1 --3 |   NULL | NULL       |
| 000005 | tabe 1 --5 |   NULL | NULL       |
| 000006 | tabe 1 --6 |   NULL | NULL       |
+--------+------------+--------+------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]>
```

**JOIN with WHERE**

```
MariaDB [yourSchema]> SELECT *
    -> FROM table1 t1
    -> LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2. id
    -> WHERE t2.val ='tabe 2 --4';
+--------+------------+--------+------------+
| id     | val        | id     | val        |
+--------+------------+--------+------------+
| 000004 | tabe 1 --4 | 000004 | tabe 2 --4 |
+--------+------------+--------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [yourSchema]>
```

Comment: Many thanks I tried it on various tables. Is it safe to say `JOIN with AND` always would produce subset of `JOIN with WHERE` (because `JOIN with AND` is going to show all rows without any condition except that some values would be just null).

Comment: correct, but in some cases you want to have all rows (to display) from table1 then is AND the better way

Answer (score 1):

For a `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` there *is* a fundamental difference based on multiplicity. This is because the LEFT/RIGHT/FULL outer joins 'preserve' records that exist in the left/right source sets, respectively, even if they are not matched:

That is: *a left join does **not** remove any rows that appear in the left set, regardless of the join condition.*

```
-- the result of the LEFT join contains every LEFT row AT LEAST ONCE
-- then we throw away the post-join rows that we don't want
SELECT * FROM l
LEFT JOIN r ON r.id = l.id
WHERE l.x = q

-- the above is logically equivalent to the following
-- where the left set is restricted before the join
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM l WHERE l.x = q) l2
LEFT JOIN r ON r.id = l2.id

-- however, it differs from just moving the condition as
-- the result of the LEFT join contains every LEFT row AT LEAST ONCE
-- (this includes the rows for which 'l.x = q' is NOT true!)
-- but we don't filter the post-join rows
SELECT * FROM l
LEFT JOIN r ON r.id = l.id
            AND l.x = q
```

When using an `OUTER JOIN` it is not possible to always move the condition. For a `LEFT JOIN`, a restrictive join condition that depends *only* on the left relation it is probably .. wrong.

If it were an `INNER JOIN` then the condition could be moved without affecting the result. This is because the INNER JOIN *restricts* both joined sets and thus there is no 'AT LEAST ONCE' clause.

Only a *valid* query can performance be reasoned about - and the Query Execution Plan will contain the relevant execution information. The very act using the 'correct' join can affect how the database executes the query.